# Grails - rendering a JSON

Tags: json, grails

I am inserting a JSON value into a H2 database using GORM in the domain i have two column
  String clobs
  Date date

```
static mapping = {
    datasource 'json'
    clobs sqlType: 'clob'
}

static constraints = {
}
```

}
from the controller i call the service method 
def createJson(){

```
    log.debug("Inserting Values")

    def builder = new JsonBuilder()
    builder.message {
        header {
            from('mrhaki')
            to 'Groovy Users', 'Java Users'
        }
        body "Check out Groovy's gr8 JSON support."
    }
    println "builder value before inserting is: "+ builder

    def jsonExec = new JsonOrm(clobs: builder.toString(), date: new Date())
    println "the builder value: "+ jsonExec.clobs
    println "the date value: " + jsonExec.date
    jsonExec.save()(failOnError:true)
    println "values saved successfully in the table!!!!!"
}
```

while executing this is the error i am getting in the browser
URI
/SampleProject/jsonOrm/index
Class
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException
Message
No signature of method: com.ws.JsonOrm.call() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[failOnError:true]] Possible solutions: wait(), last(), save(), any(), getAll(), wait(long)

Comment: Please be as specific as possible when asking questions on SO.

Answer (score 0):

To render a json string (from the CLOB), you can just parse string first and then render the json from it like this:

```
Map map = JSON.parse(jsonString)
render (map as JSON)
```

Comment: I tried as you suggested and getting the below error message  No signature of method: static grails.converters.JSON.parse() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.ArrayList) values: [[clob104: SPACE(1266 /* table: 29 id: 2 */)]] Possible solutions: parse(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest), parse(java.io.Reader), parse(java.lang.String), parse(java.io.InputStream, java.lang.String), use(java.lang.String), value(java.lang.Object)

Comment: I am inserting the json value as try{
   log.debug("Inserting Values") 
   def builder = new JsonBuilder()
   def root = builder.jsonValue{
     value{
      detail "demodetails"
      school "xxxxye"
      grade "A"
     }
   }   
   def sql = new Sql(dataSource_test)
   def preparedStetment = 'INSERT INTO TEST1(JSON,DATE) VALUES(?,?)'
   def stmt = sql.executeUpdate(preparedStetment,[root,new Date()])
  }catch(Exception e){
   print "inside exception"
   e.printStackTrace()
  }
 }

Comment: You need to convert the CLOB into the String first because JSON.parse needs a String

Comment: i tried the following and it return {} def retriveDetails(){
  def stmt
  def stmt1
  try{
   println "Retriveing values from the tables"
   log.debug("Fetching Values from table query")
   def sql = new Sql(dataSource_test)  
   sql.eachRow("select JSON from TEST1") {row ->
    java.sql.Clob clob = (java.sql.Clob) row["JSON"]
    println "CLOB length:"+clob.length().intValue()
    stmt = clob
    
    }
   stmt1 = stmt.toString()
  }catch(Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace()
   log.error("Error in Fetching Records")
  } 
 }

Comment: i am returning the stmt1 to the controller where i am rendering

Answer (score 0):

You're converting the entire CLOB object, you just want the 'contents', try:

```
stmt = row["JSON"]?.asciiStream.text
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130936/discussion-on-answer-by-mike-w-grails-rendering-a-json).